# What is largest free datababase for SQL Server engine available for testing purposes?

Tags: sql-server, database, testing, sample-data

What is largest free datababase for SQL Server engine available for testing purposes?

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the [EVE Online database dumps.](http://wiki.eve-id.net/CCP_Database_Dump_Resources)

Comment: Big thanks. There are also similar databases for MySQL, SQLite and PostreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about "largest" database, but if you're just looking for sample data, I would consider [AdventureWorks](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples) "large".

Comment: I would say that AdventureWorks would qualify as 'large'.